# On the meaning of "Class of finite groups".

Tags: group-theory, definition

What do we mean precisely when we speak about a **class of finite groups**? Is this simply a collection of some finite groups, maybe collected with a criterion (example: the class of all finite cyclic groups), or there exists a precise definition of "class of finite groups" involving some other properties?

In the case a class of finite groups is simply a collection of finite groups which follows some criterion (ex finite cyclic groups as above), what can we say about a collection of some finite groups collected randomly? Ex $\{S_5, A_3,D_4, C_9\}$... I'd call it simply a **set** of finite groups. Is this right?

Thank you all

Answer (score 4):

IF the collection $\mathcal G$ of all finite groups $(G,\times)$ is a set, then you can define a set:

$$\mathcal S = \bigcup_{(G,\times)\in \mathcal G} G$$

In particular, if $Y$ is any set, there is a group on the singleton set $G=\{Y\}$. So for any set $Y$, $Y\in \mathcal S$. That means $\mathcal S$ contains all sets. That is not allowed in set theory because of the standard paradoxes.

If you take a given infinite set, $X$, you can define all groups on finite subsets of $X$, and then that collection is a set. And every finite group is isomorphic to one of these groups on subsets of $X$, but the isomorphism is neither unique or "natural," so it can be tricky, in category theory, to deal with that fact.

There is also a confusion in the usage of the term "class" here, since, when dealing with finite groups, we talk about the classification, and that means something different than the term "class" from set theory.

Comment: Come off it. We obviously regard isomorphic finite groups as the same. That being the case, the set of all finite groups is relatively small by transfinite standards and certainly well defined.

Comment: @alma The problem (sort of) goes away if we consider finite groups up to isomorphism. But then the classes really are classes, and defining equivalence relations in that context is not the same.

Comment: @almagest Do you really need to be rude? Do you understand the problem with the fact that there is not a natural isomorphism? It is not well-defined as a set, at all.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy You can only do so if you can create equivalence classes on a class, which you can't.

Comment: Maybe I have misunderstood you. I can see no difficulty in saying there is a unique group of order 1. Are you saying that there is a difficulty?

Comment: We can form the equivalence class of isomorphic finite groups whose elements are, say, natural numbers. This is a set.

Comment: Size $1$ is easy, @almagest, since there is a unique isomorphism between those. Consider the small category $C_1$ of finite groups on $X$. Then consider taking equivalence classes up to isomorphism, $C_2$. The only way to find functors between these two is to select arbitrary representatives from each equivalence class, and arbitrary representative automorphism between any finite group $G$ and that representative of the class. This makes the the functors between these two classes completely arbitrary.

Comment: @AndréNicolas And that's in my answer! But I also indicate the problem with this.

Comment: In practice anyone dealing with groups of order $n$ is going to assume that the symbols are $a_1,\dots,a_n$ (or something similar). Now everything is finite. There are only finitely many multiplication tables one could construct. Of course, given two multiplication tables figuring out whether they represent groups, let alone isomorphic groups, is a potentially horrendous task. But that would not be helped by allowing a transfinite number of possibilities for the symbols. So I still think that it is legitimate to say that the set of all finite groups is countable.

Comment: When I talk about finite groups, I'm usually talking about subgroups of permutation groups, for example, so, no, $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ are not the elements. (And, again, in set theory, symbols don't mean anything - each $a_i$ has to represent a distinct set.) It's certainly possible to talk about finite groups without big machinery of set theory, but the question was a set theory question about groups.

Comment: I guess I have been saying that these issues are of no interest to someone working in finite groups. But I failed to read the question carefully enough. He did ask "precisely" what was meant by the class of finite groups. Also he capitalized "set" and "class", so whether wittingly or not that did invite a discussion of the set theory issues. Incidentally, I am sorry my opening comment upset you. I had not intended to be rude, just robust. I will try to be more careful in what I write! :)

Answer (score 2):

The standard definition of a *class* of groups is a a class $\mathcal{C}$ (in the set-theoretic sense) whose members are groups with the property that if $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic groups then  $G \in \mathcal{C} \Leftrightarrow H \in \mathcal{C}$.

So yes, there is a class of finite cyclic groups and a class of nilpotent groups, etc. It is customary to study the closure properties of specific classes. For example, a class may or may not be closed under subgroups, quotient groups, direct products, free products, etc.